# What is the difference between "eq()" and "=="?

Tags: rust

This is what the std says:

```
pub trait PartialEq<Rhs: ?Sized = Self> {
    /// This method tests for `self` and `other` values to be equal, and is used
    /// by `==`.
    #[must_use]
    #[stable(feature = "rust1", since = "1.0.0")]
    fn eq(&self, other: &Rhs) -> bool;

    /// This method tests for `!=`.
    #[inline]
    #[must_use]
    #[stable(feature = "rust1", since = "1.0.0")]
    fn ne(&self, other: &Rhs) -> bool {
        !self.eq(other)
    }
}
```

And the link: https://doc.rust-lang.org/src/core/cmp.rs.html#207

This is my code:

```
fn main() {
    let a = 1;
    let b = &a;
    println!("{}", a==b);
}
```

and the compiler told me:

```
error[E0277]: can't compare `{integer}` with `&{integer}`
 --> src\main.rs:4:21
  |
4 |     println!("{}", a==b);
  |                     ^^ no implementation for `{integer} == &{integer}`    
  |
  = help: the trait `PartialEq<&{integer}>` is not implemented for `{integer}`
```

But when I used `eq()`, it compiled:

```
fn main() {
    let a = 1;
    let b = &a;
    println!("{}", a.eq(b));
}
```

Answer (score 10, accepted):

It's actually quite simple, but it requires a bit of knowledge. The expression `a == b` is syntactic sugar for `PartialEq::eq(&a, &b)` (otherwise, we'd be moving `a` and `b` by trying to test if they're equal if we're dealing with non-`Copy` types).

In our case, the function `PartialEq::eq` needs to take two arguments, both of which are of type `&i32`. We see that `a : i32` and `b : &i32`. Thus, `&b` will have type `&&i32`, *not* `&i32`.

It makes sense that we'd get a type error by trying to compare two things with different types. `a` has type `i32` and `b` has type `&i32`, so it makes sense that no matter how the compiler secretly implements `a == b`, we might get a type error for trying to do it.

On the other hand, in the case where `a : i32`, the expression `a.eq(b)` is syntactic sugar for `PartialEq::eq(&a, b)`. There's a subtle difference here - there's no `&b`. In this case, both `&a` and `b` have type `&i32`, so this is totally fine.

Comment: What does this mean in practice?

Comment: @SlavaKnyazev I've added a bit of elaboration. I hope that this makes things clearer; if not, please feel free to ask for further, more specific clarification.

Comment: but there's a implementation of PartialEq::eq for `i32` and `&i32`, that's why calling 
`PartialEq::eq(&1i32, &&1i32)` works

Answer (score 5):

The difference between `a.eq(b)` and `a == b` in that dot operator does autoref/autoderef on receiver type for call-by-reference methods.

So when you write `a.eq(b)` compiler looks at `PartialEq::eq(&self, other: &Rhs)` signature, sees `&self` reference and adds it to `a`.

When you write `a == b` it desugars to `PartialEq::eq(a, b)` where `a: i32` `b: &i32` in your case, hence the error `` no implementation for `{integer} == &{integer}` `` .

*But why it does not do the same in operators?* See
[Tracking issue: Allow autoderef and autoref in operators (experiment) #44762](https://github.com/rust-lang/rust/issues/44762)

Related information:
[What are Rust's exact auto-dereferencing rules?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28519997/what-are-rusts-exact-auto-dereferencing-rules)

Comment: This should be the accepted answer. The auto-referencing done by the dot operator is the key reason why only `a.eq(b)` works.